# Best way to write a repetitive 'if' statement?

Tags: python

To write a line that when reaching a specific limit becomes a repetitive sawtooth pattern I have the following algorithm with nested `if`s,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=400
t=[0]*N
y = [0]*N
y[0]=0

low_watermark=0.9
high_watermark=0.95
limit=150

K=0.6

for i in range(0,N):
    y[i]=y[0]+K*i
    if(y[i]>=high_watermark*limit):
        y[i]=y[i]*low_watermark
        if(y[i]>=high_watermark*limit):
            y[i]=y[i]*low_watermark
            if(y[i]>=high_watermark*limit):
                y[i]=y[i]*low_watermark
                if(y[i]>=high_watermark*limit):
                    y[i]=y[i]*low_watermark
                    if(y[i]>=high_watermark*limit):
                        y[i]=y[i]*low_watermark

    t[i]=i

plt.plot(t,y,markersize=1,color='red',label='')
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("y(t))")
plt.show()
```

[image]

The problem is that for the pattern to repeat constantly I have to include the same `if` statement inside the previous `if`, because Python's indentation reads it like this.

How can I efficiently rewrite the code so that it repeats the pattern indefinitely up to a certain value of 't' without having to nest `if`s one after another? (in Fortran or C I would use a `goto` but I am afraid that in Python you can't).

Comment: Don't you just need a while loop here? `while y[i]>=high_watermark*limit: y[i]=y[i]*low_watermark`

Comment: Yes it seems exactly a while loop...

Comment: Side note: `t = list(range(N))` does exactly the same as putting `t[i] = i` in the `for` loop and I find it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a while loop instead

```
while y[i]>=high_watermark*limit:
    y[i] *= low_watermark
```

Comment: @Corralien - It would seem the op understands well enough